# Headers for tableViewController not working, returns only single header

Tags: ios, core-data, swift4

I'm trying to add headers to my TableViewController by sorting the names of different anime titles by the first letter of the name alphabetically. aName is property of my NSObject called AnimeObject where my anime titles exist in an array called managedAnime. Then I save my names to core data by creating an NS managed object called MyAnimeObject. I'm taking the data from core data and sorting it. So my problem is as I'm debugging I noticed my dictionary function orderMyAnime is only returning one section title or animeSectionTitles which is A. I need to know why this is happening so I can fix it any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my orderMyAnime function:

```
func orderMyAnime()
{
    for anime in MyAnime {
        //Time to create a dictionary
        //print(anime.aName)
        let animeKey = String(describing: anime.aName?.startIndex)
        //You need to read it one by one into an array

        if var animeValues = MyAnimeDict[animeKey]
        {
            animeValues.append(anime)
            MyAnimeDict[animeKey] = animeValues
        }else{
            MyAnimeDict[animeKey] = [anime]
        }

    }

    for (key, value) in MyAnimeDict{
        print(String(key), terminator: ": ")
        for v in value{
            print(v.aName!, terminator: ", ")
        }
        print("", terminator: "\n")
    }
    //Get the section titles from the dictionary and sort them in ascending order
    //print(MyAnimeDict.keys)
    animeSectionTitles = [String](MyAnimeDict.keys)
    print (animeSectionTitles.count, "ordermyanime")// shows that I'm only returning a single title
    animeSectionTitles.sort()
}
```

Here's my function with my titles:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    //return animeSectionTitles[section]
    if searchanimeController.isActive{
        return "Search Result"
    }
    else{
        let animeIndexTitles : [String] = ["A","B","C","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
        return animeIndexTitles[section]
       // return animeSectionTitles[section]
    }

}
```

Here's where I'm testing if I'm returning anything and come up short on the number of sections I should have:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    if searchanimeController.isActive{
        return 1
    }else{
    print (animeSectionTitles.count, "astcount")
     return animeSectionTitles.count
    }

}
```

Comment: I guess `let animeKey = String(describing: anime.aName?.startIndex)`
will return same value all the time. So, there will be only one element in the dictionary

Comment: @Satish how do I fix it then so my key returns more elements.

Comment: So I changed my key to: let animeKey = String(describing: anime.aName![(anime.aName?.startIndex)!]) but it's not working what happens is it indexes my titles isn't displaying them correctly.